# Priority with dataset cleaning

Tags: machine-learning

If I am going to clean my dataset ( for pre-processing ), is there any priority between removing some **features** or removing **data**?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by features and data here ?

Comment: So, I think I need to clean my dataset, because firstly there are some features that most of their values are zero or highly skewed. Secondly, I need to find outliers and then try to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

1/ First you should consider the possibility to imput missing data often with a median or mean or most frequent value.

2/ Then if you need and can remove only 1 row, it is better as you avoid removing a whole feature which may be usefull later. But it depends on the % of missing data in your rows and columns... and your possibility to imput and handle missing data.

3/ Later you can also do some feature selection to improve your model if needed, but is another subject.